# how to 'git add' files in only the root folder using a wildcard

Tags: git

I want to add, say, all text files in the root folder of the project.

This doesn't work:

`$ git add '/*.txt'`

What will?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the root folder of your project and then

```
git add *.txt
```

> Warning: does not work on Windows

Comment: This will also add *.txt files from subfolders, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @borek no it will not add anything from subfolders, unless you have a subfolder named `something.txt` (in this case the folder with all contents would be added).

Comment: Ha! It turns out this is OS-dependant - on Linux, it will not, on Windows, it will. Just tested on Git 1.9.x. Wasn't aware of this *important* difference..

Comment: @borek wow I didn't know either. I guess that's because in linux the shell does the wildcard expansion while in windows it does not and is `git` who it is expanding it (using the same pattern rules for `.gitignore`?).

Comment: Correct. Shell expanding on Linux can be disabled by quoting the argument, e.g., `git add '*.txt'`.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Actually under Windows `git add *.txt` will indeed add from subdirs. This seems to be due to the differences between shells like `bash` under Linux/Unix and `cmd.exe` under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes from around the wildcard:

```
git add *.txt
```

will add all text files in the current directory to the git staging area.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow:

```
git add ./*.txt
```

Greetings!